# Does for $T \in B(X)$ with $\|T\|>1$ exist $T^{-1}$?

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, inverse

Is it true if $\|T\|>1$, where $T \in B(X)$ for some Banach space $X$, then $T^{-1}$ exists?

I suppose that for $\|T\|=1$ this isn't true? Because, if we suppose that inverse exists for such operators, we can look at some operator $A$ which doesn't have inverse and then neither $\frac{A}{\|A\|}$ has inverse, contradiction.

I know that if $\|T\|<1$ then $(I-T)^{-1}$ exists and it is equal to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n$, but I don't think we can use that fact.

Comment: Also, $\Vert\alpha T\Vert=|\alpha|\Vert T\Vert$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Do you think: suppose this is true. Then if $A$ is not invertible it must be $\|A\| \leq 1$ and then to look at some operator $\alpha A$ sucht that $\| \alpha A\| >1$?

Comment: @DavidMitra Or, or, hm, we can look at some matrix which is not invertible, but has norm bigger then 1. For example $A=\begin{bmatrix} 100 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But knowing the norm (non zero) of an operator tells you nothing about whether it's invertible (look at the property of norms in my first comment).

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, I see that now.

Comment: There are inverible operators with norm exceeding $1$, though. For instance $x\mapsto 2x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invertible and nonivertible operators may have arbitrary norms: just note that $\|cT\|=|c|\|T\|$ and $T$ is ivertible if and only if $cT$ is invertible (provided $c \neq 0$)

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Stupid me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true, and it is easy to construct counterexamples.  For instance, take $X = \Bbb R^2$ with the usual norm $\Vert y \Vert = \langle y, y \rangle^{1/2}$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the standard real inner product, *viz.* $\langle (w_1, w_2), (v_1, v_2) \rangle = w_1v_1 + w_2 v_2$; let $T$ be the matrix

$T = \begin{bmatrix}  a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \tag{1}$

where $\vert a \vert > 1$.  Then

$Ty = T(y_1, y_2)^T = (ay_1, 0)^T, \tag{2}$

whence

$\Vert Ty \Vert^2 = a^2 y_1^2; \tag{3}$

taking $y = (y_1, 0)^T$ yields

$\Vert T y \Vert^2 = a^2y_1^2 =  a^2 \Vert y \Vert^2= \vert a \vert^2 \Vert y \Vert^2, \tag{4}$

whence

$\Vert Ty \Vert = \vert a \vert \Vert y \Vert > \Vert y \Vert, \tag{5}$

which implies we must have

$\Vert T \Vert \ge \vert a \vert > 1, \tag{6}$

but inspecting (1), we see that

$\det(T) = 0, \tag{7}$

so $T$ is not invertible.

This example can obviously be generalized.

Comment: Yap, I know. In comments on my question I mentioned almost the same example :-) Thanks. +1

Comment: @112233:  yes, it's really pretty simple.  Thanks for the ***plus one***; Cheers!